# Faceted and multi-line graph with autoplot zoo

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts

I'm having trouble making a faceted autoplot with three lines in each facet;
My goal is to plot mean, max and min temperatures from 5 different stations; facets will be the stations and lines the temperatures, I tried this:

```
autoplot.zoo(apply.quarterly(new_temp1[,c(7:14)], colMeans)) +
    geom_line(col="red") +
    geom_line(aes(apply.quarterly(new_temp2[,c(7:14)], colMeans)))
```

but it tells me that:

```
Error in order(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  argument 3 is not a vector
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your data to run, so I made up some simple timeseries data to illustrate how to apply geom_line() along with facet_wrap(). The dplyr package is necessary to get the data in a tidy format for easy plotting.

```
df <- data.frame(station = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 5),
        date = rep(seq(1,5), times = 5),
        mean_T = rnorm(25, mean = 75, sd = 2),
        min_T = mean_T - 20,
        max_T = mean_T + 20)

library(dplyr)
newdf = gather(df, key = type , value = temp, mean_T, min_T, max_T)

ggplot(newdf, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = temp, color = type)) +
  facet_wrap(~ station) +
  xlab("date") +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  ggtitle("Temperature at Stations")
```

The graph looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try, let's see if i can get it to work with xts